# How can ı use loops in my datetime function?

Tags: javascript, loops, date, datetime, for-loop

I have some in my hand.I need to show this data as 11 months back from the current month.

I am new js, I need to be this stution loop.

my mont array:

```
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";
```

for Example in February;

```
var mydata:[month[3],month[4],month[5],month[6],month[7],month[8],month[9],month[10],month[11],month[12],month[0],month[1]]
```

for Example in September;

```
var mydata:[month[10],month[11],month[12],month[0],month[1],month[2],month[3],month[4],month[5],month[6],month[7],month[8]]
```

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are trying to achieve, but if you are trying to iterate through the months, you may let some initial value be x (for example if you want the start to be February, let x=2), then use x=(x+1)%12 (i.e. when x+1 = 12, 12%12 will give you 0)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use modulo for this `%` which finds the reminder. So you never get out of bounds of your month array.

Here a quick a example:

```js
const month = [];
month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

const getMonths = (fromMonth) => {
  const mydata = [];
  for(let i = 2; i <= 12; i++) { 
      mydata.push(month[(september + i) % 12]);
  }
  return mydata;
}
const september = 8;
console.log(getMonths(september));
```

Comment: Yes this code  correct thank you, but ı change one things ;
const dte=new Date();
const m1=dte.getMonth();
 for(let i = m1 ; i <= 10; i++) {
      mydata.push(month[(i) % 12]);
  }

Comment: This returns 12 months, not 11.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating a new array called newMonths to reorder months.
It will be a recursive function . 
I hope it helps.

```html
<script >

var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
var month = []; 

month[0] = "January";
month[1] = "February";
month[2] = "March";
month[3] = "April";
month[4] = "May";
month[5] = "June";
month[6] = "July";
month[7] = "August";
month[8] = "September";
month[9] = "October";
month[10] = "November";
month[11] = "December";

var newMonths = []; 

nextMonths =( current ) =>{
 if( newMonths.length===12  ){
 return null; 
 }else{
  let c = current < 12 ? current : 0 ;   
  let t = month[ c ] ;

 newMonths.push( t ); 
 return nextMonths( c + 1 ) ; 
 }

} 


  nextMonths( n + 1 );
  
  console.log(  "current month  is"  , month[ n]  ); 
  console.log(  "new Array "  , newMonths   );
  
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A loop isn't necessary, you can just splice from the current month + 1 to the end of the month array and the add the months from the start to the current month - 1, e.g.

```js
/*
** @param {number} monthNumber - calendar month number in range 1 to 12
** @returns {Array} array of months from monthNumber + 1
**                  to monthNumber - 1
*/
function getMonthArray(monthNumber) {
  let month = [,"January", "February", "March", "April",
    "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
    "October", "November", "December"];
  return month.splice(monthNumber + 1).concat(month.splice(1, monthNumber - 1));
}

console.log(getMonthArray(1));  // for January
console.log(getMonthArray(2));  // for February
console.log(getMonthArray(6));  // for June
console.log(getMonthArray(12)); // for December
```

An elision is required at the start of the month array to prevent attempts to access negative indexes when splicing to `monthNumber - 1`.

The input month number can be changed to zero indexed, but I think calendar indexing is more suitable.

If you want to pass it a Date object (and use zero indexed months), then:

```js
/*
** @param {Date} date - date to use for month number
** @returns {Array} array of months from month + 1 to month - 1
*/
function getMonthArray(date) {
  let m = date.getMonth();
  let month = [,"January", "February", "March", "April",
     "May", "June", "July", "August", "September",
     "October", "November", "December"];
  return month.splice(m+2).concat(month.splice(1, m));
}

console.log(getMonthArray(new Date(2020, 0)));  // for January
console.log(getMonthArray(new Date(2020, 1)));  // for February
console.log(getMonthArray(new Date(2020, 5)));  // for June
console.log(getMonthArray(new Date(2020, 11))); // for December      
console.log(getMonthArray(new Date())); // current month
```